# How to properly use AJAX with express

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, udp

I have created a udp client in node js that sends a udp packet every 10 seconds. I want to use ajax that will create a refresh button and the client can get the newest message from udp when the button is pressed. below is what i have so far. any help would be nice, let me know if this is confusing

node js

```
var PORT = 69;
var HOST = '192.168.0.136';
var dgram = require('dgram');
var message = new Buffer('10');

var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

setInterval(function() {
client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function(err, bytes) {
  if (err) throw err;

});

},10000);

client.on('message', function (message) {
    var data= message.toString();
    console.log(data);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //render index.ejs file
    res.render('index', {val:data});
});


app.get('/ajax', function(req, res) {
    res.send(data);
});

});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/request.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Val: <span id="val"><%=val%></span></h1>

<button id="loadRequest">Refresh</button>

</body>
</html>
```

js
    $(function() {
        $('#loadRequest').click(function() {
            $.get('/ajax', function(res) {
                $('#val').append(res);
            });
        });
    });

I can get the current message right now but when i press refresh it does not update to new message. I know my mistake is probably in the ajax request but I do not know where to start to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax request isn't posting any data, so req.body is empty. Also, `req.body.ip` and `req.body.port` are not included automatically, so you have to send them with the response too. To get the host and IP, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/). You can use a form to get the values, create them yourself with a function, or even hard code them, but they have to be sent with the ajax request. Try formatting your request like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#loadRequest').click(function() {
    $.post('/output2', {
      number: 42, //post a hard coded value
      host: someVar, //post the value from a variable you create
      ip: $('#someInput').val() //post the value from a input
    }, function(res) {
      $('#val').text(res);
    });
  });
})
```

Update:

From this [SPO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540583/hostname-vs-ip-address) : A host name is a combination of the name of your machine and a domain name (e.g. machinename.domain.com). The purpose of a host name is readability - it's much easier to remember than an IP address. All hostnames resolve to IP addresses, so in many instances they are talked about like they are interchangeable.

Number is whatever use as the value for number. You don't actually need to send any data if it's not necessary for the request you can just use an empty object `{}` (although then you should probably use a get request if that's the case). I'm not sure why you want the host and ip, I included them because they were in your original code, I assumed they were used for something not included with the snippet. If you don't need them they're not required.

You don't need to turn the keys into strings, but it won't hurt anything. Both `'number'` and `number` will work. They just become the keys in your `req.body` and any other keys will return `undefined`. In the example above your `req.body` would be an object like this:

```
{
 number: 42,
 host: theValueOfSomeVar, //if you send a variable it sends the value, not the variable itself
 ip: theValueOf$('#someInput').val()
}
```

Then in your route `req.body.number === 42`, `req.body.host === theValueOfSomeVar`, `req.body.ip === theValueOf$('#someInput').val()` and `req.body.anyOtherKey === undefined`

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but I think so...instead of rendering the data and sending it on every message, make 30 calls and push each message into an array then send the array to the front end and use jQuery to add one message every 10 seconds in your success callback.

New new Node.js code (with client.on):

```js
app.post('/output2', function(req, res) {
  let HOST = 192.168.0.136;
  let PORT = 69;
  //Reading in the user's command, converting to hex
  let message = Buffer.from(42, 'hex'); //new Buffer(str[, encoding]) is deprecated

  //Sends packets to TFTP

  client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function(err, bytes) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });

  client.on('message', function(message) {
    let msg = new Buffer(message, 'hex');
    res.send(msg);
  });
});
```

New new jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#loadRequest').click(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var requestLoop = setInterval(function() {
      $.post('/output2', {
        number: 42, //post a hard coded value
        host: someVar, //post the value from a variable you create
        ip: $('#someInput').val() //post the value from a input
      }, function(res) {
        $('#val').append(res);
      });

      count++;
      if (count >= 30) {
        clearInterval(requestLoop);
      }
    }, 10000);

  });
})
```

Comment: Do the ip and host need '  ' around it?

Comment: @patidar There wasn't enough space in a comment, so I edited my answer with the info you wanted :-)

Comment: So I updated my code to include yours but I am still really confused. So is the number 42 sent to the app.post() method. I am sorry if I am being dumb, but I am having hard time comprehending it.

Comment: @patidar You're not dumb, this stuff is confusing! Yes, the number 42 is sent to your post route as part of the post request. The `$.post()` method takes multiple parameters, but only the url is required. This is the pattern:
`$.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )` 
The url is the route you're posting to, data is an object or string that will be sent to the post route and becomes req.body in your node route, success is a function that takes an argument that represents the response object from the server and the dataType is the type of return data expected.

Comment: @patidar You can read all the nitty gritty details in the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: I hard coded the ip address, port, and data in the code above. I am not sure if the ajax call is correct above.

Comment: When i click on the refresh button, i get error that says "cant set headers after sent" and "req.next is not a function"?

Comment: client is using the dgram module to send a udp packet to a udp server and receive data back.

Comment: So i have a udp server running on 192.168.0136:69 and if you send any message to it, the time is outputted as the acknowledgement by the server. So i have set it up that "42" is sent every ten seconds to the udp server. I want the ajax to get the new acknowledgement data when the refresh button is pressed.

Comment: If you remove the interval and only make the request to your udp server once, do you still get the error?

Comment: Nope it works then. But it doesn't work when i try to refresh when after the original message has been received.

Comment: Try adding 
`if (timesRun >= 30) {
    res.end();
  }`
after the `client.on`

Comment: nope same error. I think its because you can not call res.render more than once?

Comment: You're right about res.render (I should have remembered that) maybe try building an array of the messages and sending that, then use your front end JS code to do the timing. Take a look a the edits I made to the answer above and let me know if it works.

Comment: But i still not client.on, which is not in your code

Comment: I refactored the node route in my answer to include client.on. Let me know if it works

Comment: I just want to say thank you for helping me. The code does not work. I updated my code up top, maybe can you directly edit that code ?

Comment: The message is not being sent to udp anymore

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help :-) I edited my node route above and moved the msgArr.push into the client.on, see if that changes anything

Comment: it says "hex is not a function"

Comment: What happens if you change it to ` msgArr.push(message)`  ?

Comment: i changed that and i change var message= new Buffer('42') . and i got this as the output "[{"type":"Buffer","data":[52,49]}]"

Comment: and in the console got the "cannot set header" error again

Comment: Pretty sure res.send, res.end, res.render will all give that error.

Comment: What if you made the route make a single request and then repeated the call on the front end?

Comment: I made some changes above in the New new Node.js code New new jQuery code blocks in the answer. Let me know how it turns out!

Comment: I ran the code and it downloads the output in a file rather than on a web page.

Comment: And when another message is send, the error "can't set header" comes again.

Comment: maybe you need to add `res.end()` after `res.send()` for the file

Comment: but no where in your code, is index3.ejs is called or used?

Comment: Sorry I've never used ejs, so I skipped it. It will probably fix the file download issue. I'm not sure about the can't set headers error, res.send() should close the response.

Comment: is there a way for the output to show up on html page then? I wanted the user to send a message and then on /output2 html page, the message received would show. then a refresh button on that page would when clicked update the message if there was a new one??

Comment: what was it outputting before when you used index3.ejs?

Comment: Before i just had the console spit out the response.

Comment: I did some research and I think the issue with the headers is that you're never closing the stream from the udp server, so the stream is still open when you try to make a second request and so the headers are already set when you make the second request. Look into (fs.ReadStream)[https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream] or use whatever module you're  using to create the stream to close it, but I think that might fix the header error

Comment: For the file issue, TFTP is a file transfer protocol, so what it sends you is a file. You could save it and then use fs.readFile to read what's in the file and add that to the dom, but that's not very efficient and it seems like there should be something better. I will have to think about that

Comment: Can you look at the updated code to see if you can see any mistakes? I want the refresh button to get new data.

Comment: The only obvious thing I see is that you have `console.log(data);` but `data` is not defined. Is it working? What happens when you click the refresh button?